# How to search for header files in usr/include/linux

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, cmake

I am writing a C++ program with cmake in Ubuntu, which uses the header file `joystick.h` in `/usr/include/linux`. By default, it does not seem that `make` can find `joystick.h` in the default directories if I use `#include <joystick.h>`. Therefore, I add the line `include_directories (/usr/include/linux)` to `CMakeLists.txt` to enable this header to be found.

The problem is, I now get all sorts of errors such as `error: redefinition of ‘struct timeval’` and `error: redefinition of ‘struct timezone’`. This seems to be because there is a header `time.h` in both `/user/include` and `/usr/include/linux`. The header guards in these files are `#ifndef _TIME_H` and `#ifndef _LINUX_TIME_H` respectively. Therefore, the only solution I can think of is to hardcode the path to `joystick.h` in my source code.

Because of this, it seems to me that `/usr/include/linux` should never be added to the search path due to these redefinition issues. Is this correct? And is my solution of hardcoding the path the best one?

Comment: Are the header guards for `time.h` different in the files ?

Comment: Can you not just use `#include <linux/joystick.h>` in your file?

Comment: Yup, that works, easy! Thanks :)

Comment: @EtanReisner psst Karnivaurus said your comment worked without at-tagging you. I bet if you moved it to an answer s/he'd give you sweet, sweet internet points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is a reason not to (and there might be I suppose) it would seem that just using `#include <linux/joystick.h>` in the source file would be the simplest solution here.